# MS-SQL 2005 full-text index on a view with outer joins

Tags: sql-server, full-text-search, indexed-view

I have a view that I'd like to apply a full text index on. It of course needs a unique clustered index to allow for the full text index.

Unforunately, I learned that you cannot create an indexed view that contains outer joins. Problem is that my view needs these outer joins!

Is there a way to make this happen, or am I going to be stuck writing a complex stored procedure?

Comment: Just a suggestion outside the context of your question...take a look at Lucene.NET.  This will provide you speedier query times along with more flexible querying capabilities.  I think they also have a plugin that can sit on top of your SQL Server database so that you don't have to create and maintain external indexes.  This has saved our but on several instances in my current project.  SQL Server just can't compare!

Comment: @Andew - Do you have a link to this plugin?

Comment: Try here for an intro: http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/IntroducingLucene.aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible to create a dummy record to join to for the purposes of this view?

Comment: Yes, that would definitely work. It would require some work to re-architect, but is probably the only solution for indexing the view. I'll mark you as correct, but I did end up going the stored procedure route, which turned out to be not so bad!